# Using third-party SDK's for Objective-C in Xamarin?

Tags: sdk, quickbase

I'm a C# developer. I don't have any experience in iOS development and I've been given a project to make an iPad app that sends data to Quickbase. I know there are SDK's out there for Objective-C, Java, and others... but can I use one in Xamarin?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a .NET SDK, you may be able to use it directly, depending on the parts of the BCL that it uses.

If you only have an Objective-C SDK, you can create a binding enabling you to use it from C#. To do this, create a MonoTouch Binding Project in MonoDevelop, add the Obj-C library to it, and write a [binding definition](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/). You can then compile the project and reference the resulting dll from your application projects.

You can find many bindings for popular Obj-C libraries in the [monotouch-bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings) repository on GitHub, which are useful example when creating a new binding, although they do not currently use the new MonoTouch Binding project type.

Comment: can you give me some reference for objective c sdk?

Comment: @mhutch can you update the links for this answer? I'm sure it's still possible, but there is some link rot due to moving the docs around over at Ximarin.

Answer (score 0):

If the said SDK is in .net, you can use it with monotouch (xamarin). You just add a reference to that library project inside MonoDevelop and you are good to go.